# Universal hashing

Tags: language-agnostic, hash

I do not quite understand how universal hashing works. For example, when I insert an item into my hash table, I have to choose a random function from my universal family of hash functions. Now I want to retrieve said item. How will my hash table know which function it has to use to calculate the hash?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @Gerben: None. This is a conceptual question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you'll use the same hash function for all the items in the table.

Comment: You mean that the (random) choice of the hash function is made at construction time, not on each insert operation?

Comment: @iuliux: Correct. The salt, if used, may differ (and will be stored with the insert), but the algorithm will be the same.

Comment: i still don't understand how to retrieve the number we hashed with a random hash function.

Comment: @user65165: You don't. You hash the value you have into either a matching hash or a different one.

Answer (score 1):

Which hash function is used is random only in the sense that they are not predictable by an adversary but the choice is a function of the key. There is a nice write up at 
http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs130a/Hashing.txt
The matrix method is easier to understand than other methods...

Comment: Any newer link? It's broken now.